# How does an Interface relate to an Abstract class?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uml

Using Visual Studio 2015, what do I use in the Toolbox to connect the interface to the abstract class? Visio has 'realization' but VS does not, unless I don't see it.

[image: My UML diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Interface Realization is a form of inheritance, I would use the Generalization connector (labelled "Inheritance" above). In terms of code, in Java, C# and C++ the syntax for generalization and realization is similar.